# Laravel8: make all dynamic inputs store into the same database table row

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I've made a form with static and dynamic inputs that I need them all to be stored in the same row of a database. Right now where I input them they generate a new row in DB for the dynamic inputs. Am I supposed to do a custom_id input in order to store them properly?
Here is the code from my controller:

```
 public function createClients(request $request){
        $clients = new Clients;
        $clients->nume=$request->nume;
        $clients->locatie=$request->locatie;
        $clients->cif=$request->cif;
        $clients->cif1=$request->cif1;
        $clients->tara=$request->tara;
        $clients->judet=$request->judet;
        $clients->rgc=$request->rgc;
        $clients->rgc1=$request->rgc1;
        $clients->rgc2=$request->rgc2;
        $clients->rgc3=$request->rgc3;
        $clients->localitate=$request->localitate;
        $clients->tip=$request->tip;
        $clients->strada=$request->strada;
        $clients->categorie=$request->categorie;
      
     
        foreach ($request->addMoreInputFields as $key => $value) {
            Clients::create($value);
        }
     
        return back()->with('success', 'New subject has been added.');
```

Also here is my form and scripts:

```
<form action="{{route('createClients')}}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-6" style ="float:left;" >
<div class="row">
<input type="text" name="nume"  class="form-control" placeholder="Nume Client">
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="">CIF</label>
    <select name="cif" size="1" class="text" style="width:200"><option value="" selected="selected"> - </option><option value="RO">RO - Romania</option><option value="CNP">CNP - Cod Numeric Personal</option><option value="PAS">PAS - Numar Pasaport</option><option value="SRV">SRV - SUA</option><option value="AT">AT - Austria</option><option value="BE">BE - Belgia</option><option value="BG">BG - Bulgaria</option><option value="CY">CY - Cipru</option><option value="CZ">CZ - Republica Ceha</option><option value="DE">DE - Germania</option><option value="DK">DK - Danemarca</option><option value="EE">EE - Estonia</option><option value="EL">EL - Grecia</option><option value="ES">ES - Spania</option><option value="FI">FI - Finlanda</option><option value="FR">FR - Franta</option><option value="GB">GB - Marea Britanie</option><option value="HU">HU - Ungaria</option><option value="IE">IE - Irlanda</option><option value="IT">IT - Italia</option><option value="LT">LT - Lituania</option><option value="LU">LU - Luxemburg</option><option value="LV">LV - Letonia</option><option value="MT">MT - Malta</option><option value="NL">NL - Olanda</option><option value="PL">PL - Polonia</option><option value="PT">PT - Portugalia</option><option value="SE">SE - Suedia</option><option value="SI">SI - Slovenia</option><option value="SK">SK - Slovacia</option><option value="TR">TR - Turcia</option><option value="UK">UK - Marea Britanie</option></select>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="cif1" value="" size="16" maxlength="13">
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="">Reg Com</label>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="rgc" value="" size="16" maxlength="13">
      <select name="rgc1" size="1" class="text" style="width:140"><option value="" selected="selected"> - </option><option value="40">40 - BUCURESTI</option><option value="01">01 - ALBA</option><option value="02">02 - ARAD</option><option value="03">03 - ARGES</option><option value="04">04 - BACAU</option><option value="05">05 - BIHOR</option><option value="06">06 - BISTRITA-NASAUD</option><option value="07">07 - BOTOSANI</option><option value="08">08 - BRASOV</option><option value="09">09 - BRAILA</option><option value="10">10 - BUZAU</option><option value="11">11 - CARAS-SEVERIN</option><option value="12">12 - CLUJ</option><option value="13">13 - CONSTANTA</option><option value="14">14 - COVASNA</option><option value="15">15 - DIMBOVITA</option><option value="16">16 - DOLJ</option><option value="17">17 - GALATI</option><option value="18">18 - GORJ</option><option value="19">19 - HARGHITA</option><option value="20">20 - HUNEDOARA</option><option value="21">21 - IALOMITA</option><option value="22">22 - IASI</option><option value="23">23 - ILFOV</option><option value="24">24 - MARAMURES</option><option value="25">25 - MEHEDINTI</option><option value="26">26 - MURES</option><option value="27">27 - NEAMT</option><option value="28">28 - OLT</option><option value="29">29 - PRAHOVA</option><option value="30">30 - SATU MARE</option><option value="31">31 - SALAJ</option><option value="32">32 - SIBIU</option><option value="33">33 - SUCEAVA</option><option value="34">34 - TELEORMAN</option><option value="35">35 - TIMIS</option><option value="36">36 - TULCEA</option><option value="37">37 - VASLUI</option><option value="38">38 - VALCEA</option><option value="39">39 - VRANCEA</option><option value="51">51 - CALARASI</option><option value="52">52 - GIURGIU</option></select>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="rgc2" value="" size="7" maxlength="6">
      <select name="rgc3" size="1" class="text"><option value="" selected="selected"></option><option value="2022">2022</option><option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2019">2019</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1990">1990</option></select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="text" name="localitate" id="localitate" class="form-control" placeholder="Localitatea">
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="">Tip Furnizor</label>
      <td class="hilite2"><select name="tip" size="1" class="text"><option value="1">Furnizor</option><option value="2">Beneficiar</option><option value="3">Ambele</option><option value="4">Transportator</option><option value="5">Casa de Expeditie</option></select></td>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="">Situatie</label>
        <select name="categorie" size="1" class="text"><option value="0" selected="selected">NOU</option><option value="1">BUN</option><option value="2">RAU</option><option value="7">FACTORING</option><option value="8">MOTORINA</option><option value="9">CESIUNE</option></select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="">Agent</label>
        <select name="agent" size="1" class="text"><option value="0" selected="selected"></option><option value="1">admin</option><option value="21">alexandru</option><option value="20">taga</option></select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="">Contract</label>
<input type="text" name="contract" class="text">
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="obs">Observatii</label>
    <textarea name="obs" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

</div>
  <div class="col-6" id="dynamicTable" style ="float:right; maxlength=6;">
  <div class="row">
  <input type="text" class="text" name="tara" id="tara" placeholder="tara" value="" size="16" maxlength="13">
    <label for="">Judet</label>
    <select name="judet" id="judet" size="1" class="text"><option value="" selected="selected"></option><option value="B">BUCURESTI</option><option value="B1">SECTOR 1</option><option value="B2">SECTOR 2</option><option value="B3">SECTOR 3</option><option value="B4">SECTOR 4</option><option value="B5">SECTOR 5</option><option value="B6">SECTOR 6</option><option value="AB">ALBA</option><option value="AR">ARAD</option><option value="AG">ARGES</option><option value="BC">BACAU</option><option value="BH">BIHOR</option><option value="BN">BISTRITA-NASAUD</option><option value="BT">BOTOSANI</option><option value="BV">BRASOV</option><option value="BR">BRAILA</option><option value="BZ">BUZAU</option><option value="CS">CARAS-SEVERIN</option><option value="CL">CALARASI</option><option value="CJ">CLUJ</option><option value="CT">CONSTANTA</option><option value="CV">COVASNA</option><option value="DB">DAMBOVITA</option><option value="DJ">DOLJ</option><option value="GL">GALATI</option><option value="GR">GIURGIU</option><option value="GJ">GORJ</option><option value="HR">HARGHITA</option><option value="HD">HUNEDOARA</option><option value="IL">IALOMITA</option><option value="IS">IASI</option><option value="IF">ILFOV</option><option value="MM">MARAMURES</option><option value="MH">MEHEDINTI</option><option value="MS">MURES</option><option value="NT">NEAMT</option><option value="OT">OLT</option><option value="PH">PRAHOVA</option><option value="SM">SATU MARE</option><option value="SJ">SALAJ</option><option value="SB">SIBIU</option><option value="SV">SUCEAVA</option><option value="TR">TELEORMAN</option><option value="TM">TIMIS</option><option value="TL">TULCEA</option><option value="VS">VASLUI</option><option value="VL">VALCEA</option><option value="VN">VRANCEA</option></select>
    <label for="">Cod Postal</label>
    <input type="text" id="cp" class="text" name="cp" title="cod postal" value="" size="6" maxlength="6">
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="text" id="strada" name="addMoreInputFields[0][strada]"  class="form-control" placeholder="Strada">
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="text" id="telefon"  name="addMoreInputFields[0][telefon]"  class="form-control" placeholder="telefon">
  <div class="row">
  <input type="text" id="email" name="addMoreInputFields[0][email]"  class="form-control" placeholder="email">
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="text" id="banca"  placeholder ="banca" class="form-control" name="addMoreInputFields[0][banca]" class="text">
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="text" placeholder="iban" class="form-control"  id="iban" name="addMoreInputFields[0][iban]" class="text">
</div>
<td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td> 
  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
</form>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var i = 0;
       
       $("#add").click(function(){
      
           ++i;
      
           $("#dynamicTable").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields['+i+'][banca]" placeholder="banca" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields['+i+'][iban]" placeholder="iban" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields['+i+'][locatie]" placeholder="locatie" class="form-control"/></td><td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields['+i+'][strada]" placeholder="strada" class="form-control"/></td><td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields['+i+'][telefon]" placeholder="telefon" class="form-control" /></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td></tr>');
       });
      
       $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
       });  
      
</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.6/handlebars.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/chart-area-demo.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/chart-bar-demo.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/datatables-demo.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/datatables-simple-demo.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/scripts.js') }}"></script>
```

And an image from my database (i inputed random letters just to see if it works, those 2 rows should be only one but because its dynamic input it doesn't add up) [image]

Should I make a new migration to add more tables into DB such as email2, telefon2 banca2 iban2 etc? Or is there something wrong in my code.

Comment: are you submitting the form twice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your trying to do here, but you are creating a new Clients every loop in the foreach

Also your are not saving the $client with the static fields

Assuming you have a column for every dynamic field and have them in your [$fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment) array in the Clients model
You could do something like this instead of your current foreach

```
foreach ($request->addMoreInputFields as $key => $value) {
        $clients->$key = $value;
    }
 $clients-save();
```

You didn't show your database table so I'm not sure if it will work, remember that for each field there needs to be a column in your table, the $clients->num value will store in the num column and so on, so if a dynamic field has the same name as a static field, the dynamic field will replace the static one  if you use the code I provided. If you are trying to store several "clients" each client should be in its own row